# use spring cloud gateway with oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

> i face a problem when i using spring cloud gateway
>
> is if any dependency call spring-boot-starter-tomcat   directly or recursively
>
> it will not work because it will start the embedded  tomcat server not the netty server that spring cloud gateway use

i started to solve this problem by excluding this dependency

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

> the spring cloud gateway worked successfully
>
> but sometimes i want to use spring-cloud-starter-oauth2    to use @EnableOAuth2Sso

i start to use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

> at that time i face the big issue that throw exception saying
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration
>   ......
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing same issue

Comment: I am also facing the issue, and after spending almost 2 days unable to find anything ... just wanted to know if the issue is addressed in someway and is there some reference document that can be referred.

Answer (score 3):

As you've seen, the Spring cloud gateway uses the reactive model and is based on netty rather than tomcat. The reactive change is a major shift and currently isn't supported by Spring Security but work is in progress on it and you can track it at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/179

Comment: I am also facing the issue, and after spending almost 2 days unable to find anything ... just wanted to know if the issue is addressed in someway and is there some reference document that can be referred

Answer (score 0):

Use the following dependencies (I copied from my build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
}
```

Code your gateway app minimally as follows

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    @Bean
    public ForwardedHeaderTransformer forwardedHeaderTransformer() {
        return new ForwardedHeaderTransformer();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configure in application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: XXX
            client-secret: YYY
```

I am actively building my stack that uses OAuth2 with Docker Swarm Discovery https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo.git so you can see how it would work in action.

Answer (score -2):

spring boot 2.1 with spring security 5 have resolve this problem 
see this [example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-gateway-oauth2login)